# How May I Determine if a Number is Divisible by a Given Set of Numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I mathematically identify whether or not a number is divisible with no remainder using any combination of a given set of numbers?

Example:

Set of Numbers: 500, 250, 125, 75

Dividend: 650

I know that I can divide 650 by 500 which results in a remainder of 150 which is then divisible by 75 with no remainder, but how can I accomplish that mathematically without walking through the numbers programmatically?

I want to be able to identify that 650 meets that criteria, and that 651 does not.

Comment: Note that all your numbers are multiples of $25$ so to have a remainder of $0$ your number must be a multiple of $25$.

Comment: Are you asking whether _any_ combination of the numbers adds to the appropriate value? For instance, consider the set of numbers (7,4) with a dividend of 26.  Then dividing 26 by 7 leaves a remainder of 5 which isn't divisible by 4, and dividing 26 by 4 leaves a remainder of 2, but we can still write $26 = 2\times 7 + 3\times 4$.  If so, then what you're talking about is commonly known as the _McNugget problem_ and you can probably find some information under that name.